# html to pdf free linux based command line tool

Tags: html, perl, pdf

sorry for repost the question maybe something was update in the past year or so..
All the answers here are from few years back, 
I am searching for html to pdf free linux based tool.
currently I am using wkhtmltopdf which has flaws (line breaks etc..)

The html contain CSS and canvas tags

I tested the firefox print to pdf and it work well, but I can not use firefox in my installation. maybe there is free tool based on the gecko engine already out there.

I looked also on the perl modules but none of them support CSS .

Thanks
ER

Comment: It turns out that this is a very hard problem. I'm not surprised that there is no easy tool.

Answer (score 2):

There's another tool [CutyCap](http://cutycapt.sourceforge.net/)  that also renders via WebKit, although I haven't used it myself.

Comment: Nice find. It seems to work decently. Still I maintain that since PDF and HTML/CSS are very different markups there is never going to be a great conversion engine! +1 for you, still -1 for the OP.

Comment: Indeed using this tool I can render this very page to both pdf and png. The png looks great, the pdf ... not so much.

Comment: Joel thanks for checking that is the major problem the PDF does not come up very nice usually with lines breaks any other suggestions ?